# Automatic duplicate-post notice shouldn't count as a revision to reopen-queue a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, re-open

[Question 16050](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/16050/revisions) is on [the reopen queue](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/6324) because it "was *edited* after it was closed" (quoting from that page, emphasis in the original). In fact, the only revision after closure-as-duplicate was revision 4, [Community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)'s adding a notice indicating the duplicate. I think that *that* edit should not count as an edit sufficient to put the question on the reopen queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was one of several unfortunate oversights that we made when we tweaked the criteria for posts to find their way into the queue. It's been fixed, sorry about the noise :)